# Bootstrap Nav Tabs - Fire Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a basic Bootstrap tab structure, where I wish to fire a Javascript event once the tab is clicked. I can't figure out how to do this. This is the code I have come up with so far:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1"> tab(<?php echo $count ?>) </a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"> tab(<?php echo $count3 ?>) </a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"> tab(<?php echo $count2 ?>) </a></li>                    
            </ul>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$("#menu2").click(function() {
        alert('yes, the click actually happened');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu2"]').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
 $('[href=#menu2]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
             alert('Your Code')
 });
```

This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/